# Calling same method from two different class

Tags: java, methods

```
public boolean createPricebreakupOrder(int x, int y) {
    boolean returnFlag = false;

    try {
        if (x == y) {
            returnFlag = true;
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("Exception while Price Breakup Create" + e.getMessage());

        returnFlag = false;
    }

    return returnFlag;
}
```

Now I am calling this method from two different classes; and passing the same parameter in, from each class. For the first class, the method is getting executed and `returnFlag = true`. While for other, even with the same parameters, it is  returning false.

Comment: is this a simplified example? Did you check if you recieved any exception in there, as this would explain the `false` return.

Comment: Could you show your code of the classes which call this method? The error must be in the calling class. Regarding the `createPricebreakupOrder` method you should always return the same value for `returnFlag`. Also, you do not need to catch any Exception in your method as the block code can not throw anything. But it seems that the code you post is just an example.

Comment: please post the piece of the code where you are calling this method

Comment: first, you can just return true or return false. avoid using a variable. second, just use the debugger : put a breakpoint in the beginning and follow the flow line by line.

Comment: @Belun: Although some software houses insist on exactly one `return` per function. (I don't).

Comment: @Bathsheba look for another job :)

Answer (score 2):

Be assured that because the code in the `try` block does not ever throw an exception, your function is equivalent to

```
public boolean createPricebreakupOrder(int x, int y)
{
    return x == y;
}
```

There is nothing non-deterministic about this function: the same input parameters will yield the same result.

If `x` and `y` were actually `Integer` types then it's possible that `==` will fail due to reference comparisons or, perhaps, an NPE is thrown when auto-unboxing a `null` `Integer` to an `int` when the function is called.